# Avoid close of uib-typeahead search result

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead

I have searched, but still could not find any valid solution for *avoiding* the typeahead popup (drop down) to close.

I want to prevent typeahead closing the drop down.,

Could not find any matching eventhandler to be attached when clicking out-side the search-result dropdown. 
doc: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#typeahead

version: ui-bootstrap-tpls.js, 1.3.3

```
    <div >
        <input type="button" class="btn-primary" value="Filter" >

        <input type="text"
            autocomplete="off" class="search-box form-control" name="top-search" ng-model="searchController.searchQuery" uib-typeahead="element as element.Name for name in searchController.getSearchResult($viewValue)"
            typeahead-template-url="search-result.html" typeahead-min-length="3" typeahead-on-select="searchController.onSelect($item)"
            typeahead-wait-ms="250" />

    </div>
```